# Как изменить стандартные точки слайдера в slick-carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

Есть стандартные точки(`dots`) слайдов в `slick-carousel`. Но их нужно заменить куском `html`-кода. Как это сделать? Пробовал таким образом:

```
$('.myDots').append('<button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control" aria-controls="slick-slide" aria-label="" tabindex="0"><div class="dot-play"><p class="play-title">У меня в этот момент три очка сжалось</p><div class="descr-play-dot"><p>Рассмеши комика</p><p>08:49</p></div></button>')

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.myDots')
    });
});
```

**Но не получилось.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо точек нужно сделать блоки, как на картинке(справа от видео).

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        customPaging : function(slider, i) {
            var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb');
        return '<div class="dot-play"><p class="play-title">У меня в этот момент три очка сжалось</p><div class="descr-play-dot"><p>Рассмеши комика</p><p>08:49</p></div>';
        }
    });
});
```